# Accessing SQL data from a list entry

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

First, I will describe and show how my mini program works visually so my problem is easy to understand

### Program Description

Below are the 2 widows that I use for the program:

Main Window

[image]

Input Window

[image]

The Main Window is shown at the start of the program. I used QListWidget for the 'Macros' list, which shows titles of each entry read from a Sqlite database(DB). A new Input Window is shown when the 'New' button in Main Window is pressed. The 'Save' button in Input Window saves the title and description input to DB and updates the 'Macros' list in Main Window. This will look something like this:

Enter information at Input Window

[image]

Updated Main Window

[image]

My Sqlite Table

[image]

### My Problem

I would like to be able to select an entry in 'Macros' list, press "Edit" button, and show Input Window filled with data from DB. However, because QListWidget allows only string input, I can't search using it's PK ('id').

I'm thinking of using QTableWidget instead of QListWidget. I will load the entire table but hide all the columns except the title column, so that only the titles will be displayed in 'Macros' list in Main Window. For querying, I will use the entry's PK by accessing the selected entry's 0'th index.

Please let me know if this is the correct step. If not, please describe what you would use to implement a list that only shows the title, but allows querying of its data. I am a beginner at PyQt/PySide and I would really appreciate any guidance.

### Codes

Below are the code executed when 'Save' button is pressed (plus its helper functions)

```
def save_macro(self):

    title = self.lineedit.text()
    description = self.textedit.toPlainText()

    add_sql_query = ''' INSERT INTO Macros (title,description)
                  VALUES(?,?) '''

    # Helper func that creates connection to db
    sqlhelper = SqliteHelper("entry name")

    if sqlhelper is not None:  # If db is connected:
        macro_data = (title, description)
        sqlhelper.insert(add_sql_query, macro_data)  

    self.close()


class SqliteHelper:

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None

        if name:
            self._create_connection(name)

    def _create_connection(self, name):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(name)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            print(sqlite3.version)
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)

    def insert(self, query, inserts):  # Insert
        c = self.cursor
        c.execute(query, inserts)
        self.conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel, Qt provides classes to interact with the database, for example to handle information on tables you can use QSqlQueryModel, QSqlTableModel, etc. To add a row you must create a QSqlRecord and add it to the model, for the edition you can use a QDataWidgetMapper that maps and edits the information of a row, and to delete you must remove the row and reload the entire table. To indicate which field should be displayed in the QListView, use the setModelColumn() method, which should be the column of the "title" field.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql


def create_connection(database):
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(database)
    if not db.open():
        print("Cannot open database")
        print(
            "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
            "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
            "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
            "how to build it.\n\n"
            "Click Cancel to exit."
        )
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    if not query.exec_(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Macros (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "title" TEXT,
    "description" TEXT)"""
    ):
        print(query.lastError().text())
        return False
    return True


class AddMacroDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.description_te = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()

        button_box = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        button_box.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        button_box.setStandardButtons(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok
        )

        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.title_le)
        lay.addWidget(self.description_te)
        lay.addWidget(button_box)

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.title_le.text()

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self.description_te.toPlainText()


class EditMacroDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, model, index, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.description_te = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()

        mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(
            self, submitPolicy=QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper.ManualSubmit
        )
        mapper.setModel(model)
        mapper.addMapping(self.title_le, model.record().indexOf("title"))
        mapper.addMapping(self.description_te, model.record().indexOf("description"))
        mapper.setCurrentIndex(index)

        button_box = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        button_box.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        button_box.setStandardButtons(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok
        )

        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        button_box.accepted.connect(mapper.submit)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.title_le)
        lay.addWidget(self.description_te)
        lay.addWidget(button_box)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("Macros")
        self.model.select()

        self.sql_list_view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.sql_list_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.sql_list_view.setModelColumn(self.model.record().indexOf("title"))

        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("New"))
        self.edit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Edit"))
        self.remove_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Remove"))

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("Macros"), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        )
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.sql_list_view, 1, 0)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.new_button)
        vlay.addWidget(self.edit_button)
        vlay.addWidget(self.remove_button)
        grid_layout.addLayout(vlay, 1, 1)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.new_button.clicked.connect(self.new)
        self.edit_button.clicked.connect(self.edit)
        self.remove_button.clicked.connect(self.remove)

        self.sql_list_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
            self.onSelectionChanged
        )
        self.onSelectionChanged()

    @property
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def new(self):
        d = AddMacroDialog()
        if d.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            r = self.model.record()
            r.setValue("title", d.title)
            r.setValue("description", d.description)
            if self.model.insertRecord(self.model.rowCount(), r):
                self.model.select()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def edit(self):
        ixs = self.sql_list_view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        if ixs:
            d = EditMacroDialog(self.model, ixs[0].row())
            d.exec_()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def remove(self):
        ixs = self.sql_list_view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        if ixs:
            self.model.removeRow(ixs[0].row())
            self.model.select()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onSelectionChanged(self):
        state = bool(self.sql_list_view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes())
        self.edit_button.setEnabled(state)
        self.remove_button.setEnabled(state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    database = "entry name"  # ":memory:"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not create_connection(database):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```